# Could a 4th Bible-related site fly in Area 51?

Tags: discussion

It is nice to see more traffic flowing into the BH Stack Exchange Meta site and to see positive changes occurring. It’s the place to ask “questions about how the websites work, or about policies and community decisions,” which leads me to the following:

There has been some interesting discussion about the value of launching a 4rd Bible-related site, including "Mi Yodeya", (hey, the Bible is important, right?) and a couple of moderators have indicated that they are at least supportive of the idea in principle. There has been robust discussion over the selection of an appropriate name and the definition of the distinct vision for the sister site. [Possible solution to frequent question closures, edits, migrations, and mission dilution at Bible Hermeneutics: Floating the idea of a new site](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3853/44735)

Obviously, there will always be some hesitation about embarking on any new undertaking, but I think that there is some consensus that a different site focused more on Bible applications could reduce frustration over closed questions, endless repetitions, multiple edits, etc.  and generate enthusiasm and cooperation among the related sites. Ideally, “other worldly” benefits will also accrue.

Ultimately, the only way to see if a Bible Applications site will fly in Area 51 is to fire up the engines. Worst case scenario, it sputters and we abandon it or we go back to the drawing boards. The way the process works is that we need a few people to follow the proposed site. If you’ve ever been frustrated about a question being closed or have questions that don’t seem to fit the existing sites, now is the time to see if this will solve the problem. Just the other day on one of our sites, I came across a new user complaining about the experience saying he may never post there again. I believe those kinds of complaints can be reduced and certainly should be.

Polyhat is the first to volunteer to help initiate the site, and GratefulDisciple has been helping to define the scope and will contribute when he can, but we need a few more to actively help shape the community from the beginning by asking, answering, and voting on good questions.  I can bring in plenty of people that haven’t participated yet on Stack, and I will do that eventually, but I would prefer to have support from this community which understands how SE works and can provide questions that will help distinguish this site from the existing ones.

This should not require a huge time commitment from the community and I certainly don’t want to draw away any users who are already making valuable contributions where they are. I believe that new users coming in will also increase traffic to the existing sites. Questions that fit better on C, BH, or MY would be adjusted and migrated over. The focus and quality of the questions especially on the more Christian-related sites should improve.

All we need to do is come up with 40 questions that embody the topic’s scope. If 40 questions garner at least 10 net positive votes, the site moves from the development stage to the commitment phase. So please vote early and vote often on questions you feel are interesting and a good match. Here is the FAQ link for further information. https://area51.stackexchange.com/faq

I would love to hear from members of the community who are curious to see if a Bible Applications site can fly. A simple, “Count me in, I’ll see what I can do,” will suffice. Supporters can only vote 5 times on questions, so even if a lot of people only do that, it would be a significant help. Even expressing that you are just curious to see it would work is useful information. But just a few committing to do what it takes to get this off the ground could help send it into orbit for an exciting ride!

Please indicate your interest in the comment box or provide a more detailed answer if you wish. Thank you!

Comment: Count me in, I’ll see what I can do :)

Comment: Great to hear, Tony! No pressure, but you are the kind of guy who could give a big boost to this launch! :) I also think your practical style of reasoning would be well suited to a Bible application site.

Comment: Thanks for the vote of confidence :)

Comment: I begin to wonder what's going on with this site. I have often felt resistance here to my own participation and should not be surprised if some pretense is found for banning me as happened to XXXX.  I tried logging into Area 51 for the new site, signed up for the emails of its progress, after which it would not allow me to register.  I sent a message for tech support and got directed to some site that only adds to my confusion and does not help at all.  So I'm essentially locked out of participation at 'Bible Applications' (username not found).  Given the circumstances...a conspiracy?

Comment: @Polyhat Let us believe that by faith and perseverance you will find a way to help us launch this very valuable site.

Comment: Here is something on miracles that may encourage you! https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/87083/54851

Comment: @Polyhat Please remember not to name the suspended individual. We're not looking for pretences to ban you, and I don't know why you'd think that we are.

Answer (score 1):

Almost certainly not. It's not very clear from the FAQs at Area 51, but they now require new proposed sites to show where the existing community will come from. A dozen or so people on this Meta site is not enough, they really expect there to be 100+ people. There have been very few [new sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#newest) in recent years because the process is extremely difficult to pass. There's also the issue that the site has to be clearly distinguished from other sites, and I don't think your idea is yet. (I still need to reply to the other discussion.) If you want to try, go ahead, but have low expectations.

And btw, The [Judaism](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/) site should be included, so there already are three 'Bible' sites.

Comment: Thanks for that feedback, @curiousdannii.  I know the process is arduous and stringent which is why I have not tried to launch it yet. I understand that a “Chrsitian Living” site was once  proposed but didn’t gain traction, so I am managing my expectations. Steve also suggested that I find a group outside of BH to sponsor, so I’m working on that. I’d also be interested in hearing your ideas about how to best differentiate the new site. I hear your point about the Jewish Bible site, but I think it is readily distinguishable from the proposed new mostly Christian oriented site.

Comment: Curiousdannii, Just to clarify, you are referring to Mi Yodeya, right? They really don't advertise themselves as a  Bible site and may not necessarily care to be characterized as such. "Mi Yodeya is a question and answer site for those who base their lives on Jewish law and tradition and anyone interested in learning more."

Comment: @MartinHemsley Only this site is really advertised as a "Bible" site. But like Christianity, Mi Yodeya has lots of questions about interpreting the Bible.

Comment: No problem, I modified. I do appreciate the green light to give it a go, even if the probability of success is deemed to be low. Since Stack is a community based site, the community will determine how the site should best be defined and whether it can be sustained by a motivated and faithful niche.

Comment: @MartinHemsley It is up to the site proposer to set the initial description however, and if it isn't immediately clear that it has a distinct non-overlapping scope with an existing site the staff will close it. So you'll have to think carefully how to phrase it, because "Bible Applications" sounds like it overlaps quite a lot.

Comment: I'm curious if you have any issues with the differentiation suggested by @GratefulDisicple.  Is Chrsitianity.SE a good site for a lot of practical application questions with no connection to a particular denomination?

Comment: I would hope that staff will  look even beyond the initial site description and observe how the community defines the site with questions and answers. I think one of the distinguishing aspects will be who the experts are.  Is it possible to be an “expert” in the Bible from having read and studied it faithfully for years, and hearing it proclaimed and taught in different venues without necessarily having had formal higher level education? This really goes to the heart of the question of what or who is the source of truth and how it is reliably appropriated or transmitted.

Comment: @MartinHemsley I'm pretty sure I've seen SE staff close proposals very quickly, based on the initial description, before the proposal gets very many example questions at all. That's why it's important to phrase it well when the site scopes are so close.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. If you, or anyone else here has a suggestion, I'd love to hear it. From what I've seen, the first stage proposal blurb is pretty succinct. For BH, it was "For professors, theologians, and those interested in exegetical analysis of biblical texts." For C it was "For committed Christians, experts in Christianity and those interested in learning more."

Comment: There are at least FOUR math sites on the SE network--and I have trouble seeing the distinction between three of them (the fourth being for math _educators_).  They are:  https://mathoverflow.net/
https://math.stackexchange.com/
https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Poly Well one is for a specific software app. So there are two actual maths sites, which have separate origins. I think it is Math Overflow which started independently, and has self determination rights, so it couldn't be forced to merge against its community's will. I believe there is also a difference in academic level, and one of them only allows questions at a post-grad level or higher. They're also all much older than the current Area 51 procedures.

Comment: It appears that there is precedence for an SE site to be carved out based on a specific community, whether or not its subject matter may overlap with a sister site.  In other words, _unique content_ is not the sole determining factor here--a _unique community_ is quite important as well.

Comment: @Polyhat We'll see what happens when we submit the proposal. I agree with you that site will be most clearly distinguished by how the community members interact with each other over the content. How questions are answered on BA may be very different from how they are answered on other sites. I'm hoping we will be given an opportunity to see how that develops. The proof should not be so much be in the recipe, but in the pudding.

Comment: @MartinHemsley  What has happened to me is that I have been prevented from participating on the Area 51 site, and hence can do nothing with BA. I'm quite effectively locked out with a nonsensical error message. As a logged-in user (Polyhat) I signed up for the emails to "Follow" the new site, and copied/pasted the emailed link to verify my email. It was at this step that I was sidelined, being assigned a non-descript numerical username, and not allowed to register. When, as Polyhat, I visit Area 51, it shows me suddenly as this other username, and will not permit registration. Not fair at all.

Comment: @Polyhat, I saw that someone else was not able to sign up with their regular user name, so they signed up with a numerical user name instead. Maybe you could try that until the glitches get worked out.

Comment: @MartinHemsley Are you sure that wasn't me?  Are there two users with a numerical username?

Comment: @MartinHemsley  The problem is, despite having an otherwise seemingly legitimate username (even a number should be legit), the user is still considered "unregistered" and must complete the registration process before participating.  But when I click on the link to complete registration, it comes up with the error message that my username is not found.  I have no opportunity to reach a form where I could specify that I am Polyhat.  There's no way to change anything or inform the system at all.  I used the contact page for tech support and got emailed a link to a dead end page.  And that was it.

Comment: @Polyhat I see a user216938 and user21698. Are those yours? You might try posting this issue as a separate question here on BH Meta in case others are experiencing the same difficulty. I don't think it would be wise to assume any conspiracies. There is a little upheaval right now due to the recent incident being discussed so we'll have to be patient. But hopefully the moderators here will be able to help you get things straightened out. Blessings!

Comment: Maybe post on [meta.se] about it? Area 51 is pretty quirky, and I don't know what's going wrong, but someone else will.

Comment: @curiousdannii TBH, I don't see it as merely 'quirky'.  The "system" KNOWS who I am, because when I click into it from any location where I am logged in as Polyhat, it immediately knows to identify me as that numbered user.  It doesn't require any login, nor even am I _able_ to login as anything else.  It appears rather targeted, if you ask me.  I am at this point questioning all further participation on SE.  Perhaps Martin and I, or at least I, would be better off to start a forum somewhere else where a more principled approach could be followed.

Comment: @Polyhat It's not just you, you're not being targeted. See here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=area+51+login I think Area 51 runs from a separate database, so it has caused lots of trouble in the past. I'm sorry I can't give any more specific advice.

Comment: @curiousdannii Then that begs the question, doesn't it?  If it's a known issue, how would it serve to report it and/or "beg" for help to "let me in"?  Obviously, if it's a known issue, there's no need to _make it known._

Comment: @Polyhat I was just trying to help. The discussions on Meta.SE don't just report bugs, but also offer solutions. It appears that there are several different problems with logging into Area 51. Yours might be one of them, or it could be a new one. In any case, you'll be able to find people who are much more knowledgeable on Meta.SE rather than here.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, curiousdannii. I posted a question related to your issue on the Area 51 Meta, @Polyhat. Feel free to edit it if I missed anything. I look forward to seeing some good questions from you over there in the near future. Don't lose heart!

Comment: @MartinHemsley The system tagged me with user216938 on Area 51.  It gave me +50 points for confirming my email address, awarded me the "Pioneer" badge, and left perfectly useless after that--unregistered.  I'm unable so much as to vote anything up or down.

Comment: @curiousdannii I see that on Meta.SE there are dozens of questions, many labeled as [duplicate], regarding various issues with login.  It looks like most things one might ask there in this regard would be a duplicate and be closed rather than being answered.  That said, the "solutions" I've seen to similar problems seem to be from some years ago and do not perfectly represent my case.  I'm Polyhat on the Meta site, but still end up as a user# when going directly from Meta.SE to A51.  It's not an issue with my https.  Etc.  There's no "sign up" link--I cannot even log out.

Comment: @Polyhat I wish I could offer more specific advice, but it's really not something I know anything useful about. Sorry. My advice would be to make a new post on Meta.SE, being as specific as possible, and adding some screenshots. If you make it specific and clear then they shouldn't close it as a duplicate of the wrong question at least.

Comment: Hi @Polyhat, Tiberius posted an answer on Meta Area 51. Let me know if that helps and if I can be of any further assistance.

Comment: @MartinHemsley I can see his message there, but the page does not allow me to join.  If I try to comment, it says I must have at least 50 reputation to comment.  If I try to upvote the question, it says I must have 15 rep to vote.  In other words, on that page, I am a true nobody, because even my numbered user has 51 rep.  There is a "Join this community" button at the top which, upon clicking, leads me into that numbered user deadend--but going back and refreshing the page where this question was leaves me a nobody as before. Sigh. Maybe I'm too old for this stuff. Why are others getting in?

Comment: @Polyhat Things usually happen for some reason, though we don't always figure it out. Sometimes they are just the annoying realities of living in a fallen world, and sometimes there is spiritual resistance - "We wrestle not against flesh and blood." We certainly do need your committed participation in these early stages.  I would engage with Tiberius on the Meta 51 discussion site. He seems pretty responsive and willing to help resolve these kinds of issues. Do not lose heart! Gal. 6:9

Answer (score 0):

Any new site going through Area 51 is doomed to difficulty.  Some users will simply be unable to login, sign up, or register there.  Here are screenshots of what they may encounter.

[image]

Notice the "Join this community" button at the top of the above image indicating that this portion of the site does not recognize the registered Stack Exchange user who is visiting.

Upon "joining" and attempting to complete registration the user gets this page:

[image]

. . .  followed by this one:

[image]

From this point, clicking again on the "register" link at the top will lead to the redirect page, where it stalls and the redirect never completes.

Because the user is not considered to be "registered" in Area 51, he or she will be unable so much as to ask for help there.  The user is effectively locked out from participation.

Upon seeking technical support, an email gets issued with a link to the issue that has been opened on the user's behalf.  That link takes one to a deadend zone of no activity.

[image]

As can be seen in the image, two days have passed.  There has not been a single response to this issue. It maintains the status of "In Progress" as shown in the image, with only the initial report on the record.

Area 51 has pariah-zoned me, leaving me utterly incapable of participating there.

Comment: Nice documentation! When I mentioned the problem in the Area 51 Discussion Zone, @Tyberius asked for screenshots. I'm confident we will find the solution to this, Polyhat.

Comment: @MartinHemsley  As I have indicated before, I am unable to engage with anyone on the Area 51 site.  I am not counted as registered, signed up, or logged in,and one must have a minimum of 15 rep to vote and 50 rep to comment--as a logged in, registered user.  The site counts me as a random stranger or bot, and leaves me unable to engage at all.  This is why I posted here.

Comment: Yeah, that's the weird thing because supposedly you already have 51 rep when you sign up. We'll see how it gets resolved.

Comment: I found this that maybe you can try. https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/31113/216376

Comment: Clear the cookies and use incognito.

Comment: @MartinHemsley It appears that that is the post that everyone must read _before_ attempting to join A51.  I've already mucked it up, and am in the "unregistered" category.  I see nothing on that page that offers any help for me, only instructions as to how I should have signed up.  Unfortunately, it looks like I'm out of the game now.  If I were to sign up a second account, it would break the rules here and I'd be completely gone, like you-know-who (the "unperson" that cannot be named here).

Comment: I don't know what incognito is.  I couldn't understand that part.  I know, of course, what the word means, but not how it applies in this context.

Comment: If you type incognito in your browser it should give you the option to open a private window that won't get blocked. You could delete the unregistered useless account and create one that you can use. Hopefully, it will let you use your sitewide name.

Comment: Sigh...you'd given me an ounce of hope.  I managed to enter the incognito mode, and got to the A51 sign up step.  It hung up on the redirect.  Now maybe I'm more stuck than before.

Comment: Think of it this way, Polyhat. You are being tested in the fiery furnace and your character is being developed. :)

Comment: Hey! I tried reloading that stuck page--and it let me in!  I now have 101 rep as Polyhat in Area 51.  Not sure why I don't have more rep than that, but at least it's enough to vote and comment.

Comment: No idea what to do with my other useless user account.  And do I dare click "Follow" again?  I want to follow as Polyhat, but that seems to have messed things up the first time.

Comment: @MartinHemsley As for my character--well, there's a few words I have held back on so far--but I still wished to say them.  :(  Perhaps you're right, but I don't feel very successful.

Comment: That's what counts. We can worry about the rep later. Now lets get this ball rolling! Are you able to vote and add questions?

Comment: I was able to give something like 6 votes.  Which I did to the questions that are there.  I guess I'm out of votes.  Not sure why they're rationed.  I haven't tried asking anything yet, but I assume I should now be able.  I may have to come back to this a bit later, though, as other things are pressing for the next few hours.

Comment: Yes, I would follow as Polyhat. You can ask in discussion what to do with the useless account.

Comment: Yeah, no worries. Glad we got that worked out!

Comment: @MartinHemsley It has come to my attention that there is a minimum of 200 rep on at least one site in the SE network in order to give weight to certain aspects of the new proposal in Area 51.  Because my rep has not transferred in, nor been recognized there, I will not meet this criterion.  Furthermore, despite answering a question and seeing an upvote to it there on meta.SE, my rep remained unchanged at 101, so it seems that, yet again, progress is hard, slow, and stymied.